# mod rewrite to remove facebook query string

Tags: facebook, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, iis-6, iirf

I can't get my query string to work..please help...
I have the following url:
http://betatest.bracknell-forest.gov.uk/help?fb_action_ids=372043216205703&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=288381481237582

(sorry but the page will be unavailable as it is a test internal domain link)

I want the following url:
http://betatest.bracknell-forest.gov.uk/help

I get a browser message saying 'The system cannot find the file specified.' 
I know it is because I already have a mod rewrite to remove the .htm from the page name to return clean urls but I don't know what I need to do to accept a clean url and return the page.
Here is the mod rewrite code I have:

```
RewriteRule ^/([\w]+)$ /$1.htm [I,L] #Any bare URL will get rewritten to a URL with .htm appended
RedirectRule ^/(.+)\.(htm)$       http://betatest.bracknell-forest.gov.uk/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^fb_action_ids=(.)$ #if the query string contains fb_action_ids
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !="" #if there is a query string
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1? [R=301,L]
```

I think it is because I am using R=301 twice but do not know what I need to use as an alternative.

If I append .htm from help?fb_action_ids.... to help.htm?fb_action_ids.... this returns the required page fine but I need to return the page name for the non appended url.

Many thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

OK after looking at the iirf help pages, the following strips all query strings and presents clean urls:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+)\?(.+)&(.+)\.(htm)$  /$1    
RewriteRule ^/(.+)\?(.+)$       http://betatest.bracknell-forest.gov.uk/$1 [R=301]

# Any bare URL will get rewritten to a URL with .htm appended
RewriteRule ^/([\w]+)$ /$1.htm [I,L]
RedirectRule ^/(.+)\.(htm)$       http://betatest.bracknell-forest.gov.uk/$1 [R=301]
```

iirf requires some understanding of regex and there appear to be subtle differences between it and mod_rewite.  Many thanks ofr all help given.

Answer (score -1):

These two lines will do. I've tested.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} fb_action_ids
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1? [R=301]
```

URLs with format like this: **"abc?fb_action_ids......"** will be redirected to **"abc.htm"** if you have **abc.htm**.

However, you can turn off MultiView in http.conf and if will be redirected to exact "abc" file.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply - I was beginning to think there was no one out there...I need this to work not only for help.htm but for the whole site.  so I need a redirect that works for pagename.htm where pagename is the name of the page so...http://betatest.bracknell-forest.gov.uk/pagename?fb_action_ids=372043216205703&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=288381481237582 becomes http://betatest.bracknell-forest.gov.uk/pagename or http://betatest.bracknell-forest.gov.uk/pagename.htm - thanks again for the response

Comment: OK, I've edited the above answer. It works for me but I don't know who  gave me a minus one.

Comment: Hi benck.  I tried the above and got the following in message in Firefox:The page isn't redirecting properly.  Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.  I notice that the url has changes to http://betatest.bracknell-forest.gov.uk/help?fb_action_ids=372043216205703&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=288381481237582???????????????????? - adding the ? symbol which I think it is getting from $1? - Not sure if it makes any difference but I am using iirf in IIS6 on a Windows Server.

Comment: How would it be if removing "?"? I tested on apache and it's fine.

Comment: I just tried without the ? and it get the same Firefox message without the ?????????????? in the url

Comment: Hi benck - I have spent the afternoon looking at discussions for the iirf solution we are using (http://iirf.codeplex.com/).  There are differences between this and mod_rewrite that I think is the readon why the redirects work for you and not for me.  I have posted on their discussion boards and will let you know what comes back and hopefully a solution.